# Why can't this contract assertion be proven?

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
class Foo
{
    private IEnumerable<Bar> bars;

    ...

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        Contract.Requires(bars != null);
        Contract.Requires(bars.Any());

        Bar result = bars.FirstOrDefault(b => SomePredicate) ?? bars.First();
        Contract.Assert(result != null); // This asserts fails the static checker as "cannot be proven"
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, Contracts has all the information it needs to know that `result` will not be null. `bars` has at least one element in it. If one of those elements matches `SomePredicate`, `result` will be the first such element. If not, `result` will be the first element in `bars`.

Why does the assertion fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't ensured or assumed that the elements inside of `bars` are not null. Try:

```
Contract.ForAll(bars, x => x != null);
```

Or (your actual invariant):

```
Contract.Requires(bars.FirstOrDefault(x => SomePredicate(x)) != null
               || bars.First() != null);
```

Comment: or `Contract.Requires(bars.Any(x => x != null))`

Comment: @leppie: Is either of those forms preferred? All I can find in the user documentation is "It is also possible to use the extension method `System.Linq.Enumerable.Any` instead of `Contract.Exists`."

Comment: @Matthew: If there can never be a null element, go with `ForAll`, else `Any` would work. You would also have to have `First(x => x != null)` in the latter part of the code when using `Any`. Small and subtle difference.

Answer (score 4):

The colection `bars` could still contain an item that is `null`. If that item is the first item then `result` can still be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

What if the first element of `bars` is `null`? (**A**: The assertion fails.)